# Selenium : How to find xpath of button by LinkText?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

Basically there are 3 types of Save button in a page. Now, the button which I'm trying to click on is a `type="button"` and remaining types of save are not defined as `type="button"`.For all three save buttons `LinkText` is defined as **Save**. So, is there any way to click on `type="button"` by `linkText`.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-md bgm-blue m-r-10 waves-effect" ng-click="updateUser()" type="button">Save</button>
```

Code which I tried:

```
List<WebElement> list = Util.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Save']"));
System.out.println("SaveButton"+list.size()); ///Returning 3 save button in a page
list.get(3).click();
```

Now, suppose in one page there are 4 save buttons and in another page there are 3 save buttons. So, it is not possible to make a method because each time index will differ.

If there is any way to find `xpath` by `type="button"`. Will be easy for me to make a method and call it each time I want to click on`"Save"`.

Please let me know in case of clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to click on type="button" by linkText

Actually [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-) is use to locates `<a>` elements only that contain the given link text while you're trying to locate `<button>` element. So you can not locate desire element using [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-).

> button which I'm trying to click on is a `type="button"` and remaining types of save are not defined as `type="button"`

As you are saying only desire button contains attribute `type="button"`, So it is very easy to find that element using other locator as below :-

- [`By.cssSelector()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#cssSelector-java.lang.String-) :

  - `button[type='button']`
  - `button[type='button'][ng-click='updateUser()']`
  - `button.btn.btn-md.bgm-blue.waves-effect[type='button'][ng-click='updateUser()']`
- [`By.xpath()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#xpath-java.lang.String-) :

  - `//button[text()='Save' and @type='button']`
  - `//button[.='Save' and @type='button']`
  - `//button[text()='Save' and @type='button' and @ng-click='updateUser()']`
  - `//button[.='Save' and @type='button' and @ng-click='updateUser()']`

Comment: Perfect explanation. If I'm going with method and using it everywhere the following xpath code will work-
```//button[.='Save' and @type='button']```

Answer (score 0):

As the `Save` button contains `class` attribute you can construct an `xpath` as follows:

```
findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-md bgm-blue m-r-10 waves-effect'][contains(text(),'Save')]"));
```

Comment: I think selenium does not support compound class names.